# How do I value-initialize a Type* pointer using Type()-like syntax?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, local-variables, built-in-types

Variables of built-in types [can be value-initialized like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584213/how-to-default-initialize-local-variables-of-built-in-types-in-c/2584240#2584240):

```
int var = int();
```

this way I get the default value of `int` without hardcoding the zero in my code.

However if I try to do similar stuff for a pointer:

```
int* ptr = int*();
```

the compiler (Visual C++ 10) refuses to compile that (says `type int unexpected`).

How do I value-initialize a pointer in similar manner?

Comment: Good question. You also get a similar failure for `unsigned int`.

Comment: Now the question is why would you want to do that. You can initialize pointers with 0 directly (if you know it is a pointer), and if this is hidden in some template, then `T()` will work fine... I don't get how this question gets 11 upvotes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I value-initialize a Type* pointer using Type()-like syntax?

You cannot. The syntax `T()` is defined in 5.2.3/1,2 (C++03, slightly different wording in C++11 FDIS). In particular the second paragraph states:

> The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier (7.1.5.2) for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates an rvalue of the specified type, which is value-initialized (8.5);

That means that `int()`, will create an rvalue of type int and *value-initialize* it. Now the problem is that `int*` is not a simple-type-specifier, but rather an elaborated-type-specifier. The definition of simple-type-specifier in the grammar is:

```
  simple-type-specifier:
    ::opt nested-name-specifieropt type-name
    ::opt nested-name-specifier template template-id
    char
    wchar_t
    bool
    short
    int
    long
    signed
    unsigned
    float
    double
    void
```

With type-name being defined as:

```
  type-name:
    class-name
    enum-name
    typedef-name
```

This is what makes the proposed solutions work. The creation of the typedef (either directly or through the template) creates a type-name (third type) that can be used as a simple-type-specifier (first type).

Answer (score 9):

Use a typedef to make a name for your pointer type:

```
typedef int *ip;

ip ptr = ip();
```

The same idea should work for other types that require more than one lexical element (word) to define the name of the type (e.g., `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long *`, etc.).

Comment: I'm confused, a pointer just holds the address in memory of the variable - shouldn't it just be int* x = int(), making x hold 0 which is the same as NULL? I guess I'm missing something since people keep skipping past mine, haha, I don't get what though.

Comment: @w00te: Yours will have the same effect, because 0 is defined to convert to a null pointer. At the same time, he's specifically asking about how to do value initialization, and you're *doesn't* do that ("value initialization" has a specific defined meaning in the C++ standard that's a bit different from just the general idea of initializing with a value).

Comment: Ah, I figured he just wanted to make sure his pointer pointed to null so it could be checked more effectively in later code :) Guess I misread.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't require the use of `typedef` (but exclusive to C++11), which can be useful when dealing with several pointer types:

```
template<typename T>
using alias = T;
```

then `alias<int*>` is `int*`, so you can do `int* p = alias<int*>()`.

A similar solution available to C++03, using an identity metafunction:

```
template<typename T>
struct identity {
    typedef T type;
};

int* p = identity<int*>::type();
```

Comment: The C++03 version requires a typedef, it is just hidden inside a template. The C++11 version does not create a typedef, but it does create a new type `alias<T>` which becomes a *simple-type-specifier* and thus prone to *explicit type conversion* in the *functional notation*

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
int* x = int();
```

It still assigns 0 to the pointer making it point to the NULL address since you're defaulting it with the default value of int which is 0 anyway.

Actually, it works fine for all types:

```
double* y = int();
```

The address is still a 32-bit (or 64-bit depending on platform) integer so I think it should work fine for all types if you do = int().

Comment: Wow, looks like a major breach in the type system and is unbelievably cool. Yet it won't work for `double*`.

Comment: huh, interesting :) I'll have to check that out.  I'd have thought it would have worked for all pointer types.

Comment: Yes, I meant `double* ptr = double()` which of course won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
template <typename T>
T make_default()
{
    return T();
}

int main()
{
    int *p = make_default<int*>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that doesn't work is because pointers do not have constructors.

The syntax

> `int ()`

calls (in theory)

> `int::int ()`

which initializes the variable. (More likely, the compiler just zeros the variable, but that's because it "knows" about ints).

In c++11, you can use nullptr

> `int *ptr = nullptr;`

Otherwise, you pretty much have to use NULL:

> `int *ptr = NULL;`

Comment: Of course pointers have constructors in the same way `int` has — it's all built-ins, after all. I can say `T()` if `T` is `typedef int* T`, and I cannot use `= unsigned int()` either. It's the just the purely syntactic problem of this not working with composite type names.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it
   int* ptr = new int;

[Heap pointers](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/)