# How is "int* ptr = int()" value initialization not illegal?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, initialization, built-in-types

The following code (taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067568/how-do-i-value-initialize-a-type-pointer-using-type-like-syntax/8067658#8067658)):

```
int* ptr = int();
```

compiles in Visual C++ and value-initializes the pointer.

How is that possible? I mean `int()` yields an object of type `int` and I can't assign an `int` to a pointer.

How is the code above not illegal?

Comment: Not an answer, but great question! I've never seen such a thing.

Comment: Since primitives have a 'constructor' in C++, `int()` yields the value constructed value of `int` (which is I think a C++03 specified thing) and the default value of `int` is `0`. This is equivalent to `int *ptr = 0;`

Comment: depending on the mashine, an int may be the same size as a pointer, but is should give you a warning.

Comment: @EmanuelEy: No, any zero-valued integer constant can be used as a null pointer constant, regardless of how pointers are actually implemented.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: `NULL` hasn't been allowed to be other values.  Source: [Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null)  According to [K&R](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/) `NULL` is always 0, which (in the context of a pointer) is converted to whatever the underlying null-pointer type is.  So, in C++, `NULL` is 0, irrespective of the underlying hardware.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I didn't say `NULL` could be a non-zero value. I said it could be any zero-valued integer constant (which includes `int()`).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I missed the word "zero".  My bad.

Comment: Also `int` isn't an object, even if you're using the object instantiation syntax to create one.

Comment: @fluffy: [`int` is most certainly an object](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/classes-and-objects.html#faq-7.2) in C++.

Comment: @DanielPryden That is a use of the word "object" of which I was previously unaware.

Comment: Wow, this makes C++ sound like it's purely OO, like Python, where even POD's and functions are objects :)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`int()` is a constant expression with a value of 0, so it's a valid way of producing a null pointer constant. Ultimately, it's just a slightly different way of saying `int *ptr = NULL;`

Comment: +1, the *constant expression* bit is important and missing from the top-2 upvoted answers.

Comment: does this go away with C++0x?

Comment: @NeilG: This stays the same in C++11, though there is now also a `nullptr`, which you can use instead of `0` or `NULL` in new code.

Comment: Why use NULL instead of 0? All you do is type more.

Comment: @Nils: Code clarity and declaring your intent through code. Ofcourse, with C++11, now you want to use nullptr because it also tosses the benefit of extra compile-time checks into the mix.

Comment: C++ always leaves you with enough options to have a hour long discussion about trivial things. Now how is nullptr clearer than 0? ;)

Comment: @Nils because quite obviously `0` could mean a null pointer constant or the number 0, while `nullptr` is obvious a null pointer constant. In addition, as Jamin said, it also has "extra compile-time checks". Do try to think before you type.

Answer (score 35):

Because `int()` yields `0`, which is interchangeable with `NULL`. `NULL` itself is defined as `0`, unlike C's `NULL` which is `(void *) 0`.

Note that this would be an error:

```
int* ptr = int(5);
```

and this will still work:

```
int* ptr = int(0);
```

`0` is a special constant value and as such it can be treated as a pointer value. Constant expressions that yield `0`, such as `1 - 1` are as well allowed as null-pointer constants.

Comment: Also note that C's NULL isn't necessarily `(void *)0` either. It's simply an implementation defined "integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *".

Comment: @JerryCoffin I've never used a C compiler which defined `NULL` as `(void*)0`; it was always `0` (or maybe `0L`).  (But then, by the time C90 had made `(void*)0` legal in C, I was already using C++.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: In ubuntu 11.04 and our own linux flavor, libio.h contains: `#if !defined(__cplusplus) \n #define NULL ((void*)0) \n #else \n #define NULL (0)` the current version of gcc in ubuntu is 4.5, in our system is 4.0.

Comment: "`0` is a special literal" - only because it's a constant expression, and it has the special value 0. `(1-1)` is equally special, it's also a null pointer constant, and so is `int()`. The fact of `0` being a literal is sufficient but not necessary condition to be a constant expression. Something like `strlen("")`, although it also has the special value `0`, isn't a constant expression and hence isn't a null pointer constant.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree about the correction, it's really about the constant value `0`, not the `0` literal.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas So Linux is trying to emulate all of the Microsoft errors?  I haven't used C for almost 25 years, but in the K&R C that came with Unix back then, `NULL` was 0.

Comment: @Tomalak: not really, since `NULL` is not guaranteed to be `0`. It could be `0L`, or `0LL`. In my GCC installation, in contrast to David's, it's `__null`. It would be wrong to say "`0` is `NULL`", although of course the value of `NULL` is 0 in some integer type.

Comment: @Steve: I just didn't like how `NULL` was being painted as some kind of separate, independent entity, that is "on the same standing" as `0`, rather than something used to stand in for it (and for its friends).

Comment: @Tomalak: well, I don't like `NULL` at all, which is why I don't use it. I'm just excessively precise about its shortcomings ;-)

Comment: @Steve: I do, because I don't feel like manually replacing `x`% of my `0`s when I switch to `nullptr`.

Comment: @Tomalak: yeah, not gonna bother replacing `0` with `nullptr` either. Might replace `(void*)0` with `nullptr`, and will start using `nullptr` in preference to `(void*)0`, but since that would only appear in varargs calls and maybe a few places to force overload resolution, it's not a big code change. I write `char *foo = 0;` instead of `char *foo = NULL/nullptr;` for the same reason I write `float f = 0;` instead of `float f = 0.0f;`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: ISTR Borland C++ also defining `NULL` as `(void*)0` for C (but not for C++. I always thought that the improved type safety of C++89 (what with function prototypes and the like) made this en vogue.

Answer (score 18):

The expression `int()` evaluates to a constant default-initialized integer, which is the value 0. That value is special: it is used to initialize a pointer to the NULL state.

Comment: This is missing a very important detail present in Jerry's answer: it is not enough that the expression yields the value 0, but it must also be a *constant-expression*. For a counter-example, with `int f() { return 0; }`, the expression `f()` yields the value 0, but it cannot be used to initialize a pointer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, in my rush to present an answer in the simplest possible terms I left that part out. I hope it's acceptable now.

Answer (score 13):

From n3290 (C++03 uses similar text), 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr] paragraph 1 (the emphasis is mine):

> 1 A null pointer constant is **an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero** or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; **the result is the null pointer value of that type** and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion. [...]

`int()` is such an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero (that's a mouthful!), and thus can be used to initialize a pointer type. As you can see, `0` is not the only integral expression that is special cased.

Answer (score 4):

Well int isn't an object.

I beleive what's happening here is you're telling the int* to point to some memory address determined by int()

so if int() creates 0, int* will point to memory address 0

Comment: `int()` most certainly _is_ an object.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think it is. It's a temporary of non-class type, and I think I'm right in saying that these are *not* objects as far as the C++ standard is concerned. It's a bit odd, though, the section on "temporary objects" starts out carefully talking only about temporaries of class type, but later on it talks about binding references, and of course you can bind a reference to `int()`. Define `int i;`, then no question, `i` is an object.

Comment: @Steve: I'd only expect debate over this in that "objects" are a region of storage in C++, and temporaries don't really have storage, right? 1.8/1 doesn't explicitly list temporaries, but it feels as if the intent is there to include them.

Comment: @Tomalak: yes indeed, temporaries of non-class type don't need storage unless you take a reference. Never mind though, it doesn't matter much. The statement "well int isn't an object" is only true because `int` is a type, not an object. Whether `int()` yields an object or just an rvalue doesn't affect anything anyone has said elsewhere.

Comment: @Steve: That much is undebateable :)